# Add a filter to see all broken links from a single domain

Tags: feature-request, review, broken-link

It would be very useful to have a filter in the "Broken Links" tab of the review page that would show all broken links from a single domain.

Some sites that are used frequently on certain sites (Cochrane Collaboration, I'm writing about *you*) don't care about just systematically breaking links. If you figure out an efficent way to find the new links, it would be nice if we could just get a list of all broken links for that site and go fix them all.